# UnicodeEncodeError, I can't print a dictionary from a json file

Tags: python, json, dictionary, utf-8, encode

I have a problem with reading a dictionary data from an API, I extract the information with requests.get(), and save it in a json file, but when I want to read it and extract currencies from the dictionary, it doesn't allow me:

The code is this one:

```
import requests
import json

endpoints = {"access_key": "*********************************"}
url = "http://api.currencylayer.com/list"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    response = requests.get(url, params=endpoints)
    data = response.text

    with open("simbolos.json", "w") as f:
        f.write(data)

with open("simbolos.json", "r") as f:
    json_file = json.load(f)
    print(json_file)
```

The json file is created just fine, is when I try to read the dictionary where the error occours, and I can see the json file have lots of undefined charecters, also it gives me this error when i run the code:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u02bb' in position 3878: character maps to

So I think it has to do with the encoding utf-8, but I can't find a way to solve the problem, i tried using decode and encode, but it is all the same, is there a solution for this, here is the json file created: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4f6w5q9ce2gn1i/simbolos.json?dl=0

### JSON

```
{"success":true,"terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms","privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy","currencies":{"AED":"United Arab Emirates Dirham","AFN":"Afghan Afghani","ALL":"Albanian Lek","AMD":"Armenian Dram","ANG":"Netherlands Antillean Guilder","AOA":"Angolan Kwanza","ARS":"Argentine Peso","AUD":"Australian Dollar","AWG":"Aruban Florin","AZN":"Azerbaijani Manat","BAM":"Bosnia-Herzegovina Convertible Mark","BBD":"Barbadian Dollar","BDT":"Bangladeshi Taka","BGN":"Bulgarian Lev","BHD":"Bahraini Dinar","BIF":"Burundian Franc","BMD":"Bermudan Dollar","BND":"Brunei Dollar","BOB":"Bolivian Boliviano","BRL":"Brazilian Real","BSD":"Bahamian Dollar","BTC":"Bitcoin","BTN":"Bhutanese Ngultrum","BWP":"Botswanan Pula","BYN":"New Belarusian Ruble","BYR":"Belarusian Ruble","BZD":"Belize Dollar","CAD":"Canadian Dollar","CDF":"Congolese Franc","CHF":"Swiss Franc","CLF":"Chilean Unit of Account (UF)","CLP":"Chilean Peso","CNY":"Chinese Yuan","COP":"Colombian Peso","CRC":"Costa Rican Col\u00f3n","CUC":"Cuban Convertible Peso","CUP":"Cuban Peso","CVE":"Cape Verdean Escudo","CZK":"Czech Republic Koruna","DJF":"Djiboutian Franc","DKK":"Danish Krone","DOP":"Dominican Peso","DZD":"Algerian Dinar","EGP":"Egyptian Pound","ERN":"Eritrean Nakfa","ETB":"Ethiopian Birr","EUR":"Euro","FJD":"Fijian Dollar","FKP":"Falkland Islands Pound","GBP":"British Pound Sterling","GEL":"Georgian Lari","GGP":"Guernsey Pound","GHS":"Ghanaian Cedi","GIP":"Gibraltar Pound","GMD":"Gambian Dalasi","GNF":"Guinean Franc","GTQ":"Guatemalan Quetzal","GYD":"Guyanaese Dollar","HKD":"Hong Kong Dollar","HNL":"Honduran Lempira","HRK":"Croatian Kuna","HTG":"Haitian Gourde","HUF":"Hungarian Forint","IDR":"Indonesian Rupiah","ILS":"Israeli New Sheqel","IMP":"Manx pound","INR":"Indian Rupee","IQD":"Iraqi Dinar","IRR":"Iranian Rial","ISK":"Icelandic Kr\u00f3na","JEP":"Jersey Pound","JMD":"Jamaican Dollar","JOD":"Jordanian Dinar","JPY":"Japanese Yen","KES":"Kenyan Shilling","KGS":"Kyrgystani Som","KHR":"Cambodian Riel","KMF":"Comorian Franc","KPW":"North Korean Won","KRW":"South Korean Won","KWD":"Kuwaiti Dinar","KYD":"Cayman Islands Dollar","KZT":"Kazakhstani Tenge","LAK":"Laotian Kip","LBP":"Lebanese Pound","LKR":"Sri Lankan Rupee","LRD":"Liberian Dollar","LSL":"Lesotho Loti","LTL":"Lithuanian Litas","LVL":"Latvian Lats","LYD":"Libyan Dinar","MAD":"Moroccan Dirham","MDL":"Moldovan Leu","MGA":"Malagasy Ariary","MKD":"Macedonian Denar","MMK":"Myanma Kyat","MNT":"Mongolian Tugrik","MOP":"Macanese Pataca","MRO":"Mauritanian Ouguiya","MUR":"Mauritian Rupee","MVR":"Maldivian Rufiyaa","MWK":"Malawian Kwacha","MXN":"Mexican Peso","MYR":"Malaysian Ringgit","MZN":"Mozambican Metical","NAD":"Namibian Dollar","NGN":"Nigerian Naira","NIO":"Nicaraguan C\u00f3rdoba","NOK":"Norwegian Krone","NPR":"Nepalese Rupee","NZD":"New Zealand Dollar","OMR":"Omani Rial","PAB":"Panamanian Balboa","PEN":"Peruvian Nuevo Sol","PGK":"Papua New Guinean Kina","PHP":"Philippine Peso","PKR":"Pakistani Rupee","PLN":"Polish Zloty","PYG":"Paraguayan Guarani","QAR":"Qatari Rial","RON":"Romanian Leu","RSD":"Serbian Dinar","RUB":"Russian Ruble","RWF":"Rwandan Franc","SAR":"Saudi Riyal","SBD":"Solomon Islands Dollar","SCR":"Seychellois Rupee","SDG":"Sudanese Pound","SEK":"Swedish Krona","SGD":"Singapore Dollar","SHP":"Saint Helena Pound","SLL":"Sierra Leonean Leone","SOS":"Somali Shilling","SRD":"Surinamese Dollar","STD":"S\u00e3o Tom\u00e9 and Pr\u00edncipe Dobra","SVC":"Salvadoran Col\u00f3n","SYP":"Syrian Pound","SZL":"Swazi Lilangeni","THB":"Thai Baht","TJS":"Tajikistani Somoni","TMT":"Turkmenistani Manat","TND":"Tunisian Dinar","TOP":"Tongan Pa\u02bbanga","TRY":"Turkish Lira","TTD":"Trinidad and Tobago Dollar","TWD":"New Taiwan Dollar","TZS":"Tanzanian Shilling","UAH":"Ukrainian Hryvnia","UGX":"Ugandan Shilling","USD":"United States Dollar","UYU":"Uruguayan Peso","UZS":"Uzbekistan Som","VEF":"Venezuelan Bol\u00edvar Fuerte","VND":"Vietnamese Dong","VUV":"Vanuatu Vatu","WST":"Samoan Tala","XAF":"CFA Franc BEAC","XAG":"Silver (troy ounce)","XAU":"Gold (troy ounce)","XCD":"East Caribbean Dollar","XDR":"Special Drawing Rights","XOF":"CFA Franc BCEAO","XPF":"CFP Franc","YER":"Yemeni Rial","ZAR":"South African Rand","ZMK":"Zambian Kwacha (pre-2013)","ZMW":"Zambian Kwacha","ZWL":"Zimbabwean Dollar"}}
```

Comment: try `with open("simbolos.json", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f`

Comment: The "codec can't encode" exception is (most certainly) caused by the print statement, as your title says. So reading the JSON file works just fine. Also your JSON file looks ok, having escape sequences like `"Col\u00f3n"` is totally fine. Your problem seems to be simply that your terminal/IDE console does not handle all of Unicode, but instead uses some restricted (Windows?) codepage.

Comment: I tried the encoding='utf-8', it does not work, the same error, the problem si that python can read it fine in a string form, but not as a dictionary, and i need it as a dictionary for manipulation, doing it as text will make the code more complicated and will probably make me use regex, I rather keep it as dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I expand the comment of @lenz.

When you use open on text files (read/write), you should always add the encoding: "Explicit is better then implicit" (a mantra of Python), but helps you (and others) in future to see what encoding you were expecting. Probably this is not your case (but still do it): smaller charsets uses usually single byte, and every byte is available, so in such case usually one has just wrong characters, but no errors.

So I think @lenz is right.

`print` will encode the characters for the terminal capability, so sometime just a subset could be used. Linux and Mac uses UTF-8 (usually), so no problem [but `LANG=C` supports just ASCII]. Usually the problem arise with Python on Windows: it still uses the local code page (so with just around 200 usable characters).

ASCII and Latin-1 (base of "Windows ANSI") supports just few currency symbols. Euro symbol was created a lot later (but this was added into Windows, on a spare code). Various other currency symbols are not included in Windows (but the main 5: dollar, pound, yen, cent, euro), and there are a lot of currency symbol (see [Currency symbols in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbol)).

So to print on Windows, you needs a terminal which support Unicode (and that tell Python that it uses Unicode). A workaround it is to just write to a file, and read data from that file (editors often allows you to select encoding, and some editors automatically refresh data if file change).

Comment: Well, i already wrote the data into a json file, and i can read it just fine as text, but i need it to be read as a dictionary, to be able to interact with the different currencies, like: json_file["currencies"], which will normally give me the simbols and countries, and then select the country  jason_file["currencies"]["PEN"], mostly for manipulation, and is in a dict form that doesn't allow me to print nor manipulate the data, is there a way I could do it?.

Comment: @Voltaje It is your terminal environment.  The JSON you posted loads into a dictionary and can be manipulated just fine, but you can't **print** certain characters due to your terminal/IDE configuration.  In my UTF-8 Python IDE it prints just fine, and in Windows cmd.exe with Python 3.6+ it prints just fine.  What is **your** environment?

Comment: I'm using Atom for python coding